# Python programming: Multi-variate Linear Regression

Tags: python

May i ask for multivariate linear regression, what dtypes are needed for the predictors? Object, float64 and int64 are the dtypes I have from my dataset and am curious could I just use them all as predictors? Or would I need to convert them to another dtype for example?

I have yet to try but Ijust want to make sure what I'm doing is reasonable

Answer (score -1):

For a linear regression in Python you would need numerical data types, so floats and ints are fine. Unfortunately, the model cannot interpret objects, so they are not allowed.